# Sqoop incremental export using hcatalog?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, hadoop2, hcatalog

Is there a way to use sqoop to do incremental exports ? I am using Hcatalog integration for sqoop.I tried using the --last-value, --check-column options which are used for incremental import, but sqoop gave me error that the options were invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not seen incremental sqoop export arguments. The other way you could try is to create a contol_table in hive where you keep log of the table name & timestamp when it was last exported every time.

```
create table if not exists control_table (
 table_name  string,
 export_date timestamp
);

insert into control_table 'export_table1' as table_name, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) as export_date from control_table;
```

If export_table1 is the table you want to export incrementally and assuming if have already executed above two statements.

```
--execute below at once   
--get the timestamp when the table was last executed
create temporary table control_table_now as select table_name, max(export_date) as last_export_date from control_table group by table_name;

--get incremental rows
create table new_export_table1 as select field1, field2, field3, .... timestamp1 from export_table1 e, control_table_now c where c.table_name = 'export_table1' and e.timestamp1 >= c.last_export_date;

--append the control_table for next process
insert into control_table 'export_table1' as table_name, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) as export_date from control_table;
```

Now, export the new_export_table1 table which is incrementally created using sqoop export command.

Comment: Does sqoop work for updating rows in export ? From the new_export_table1, if I run sqoop, would it update old rows ?

Comment: @VoodooChild Yes, if your table export_table1 in Hive have a unique field & the same field is a primary key in the end table then the **sqoop** should update the corresponding fields. Refer to https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_inserts_vs_updates

Answer (score 0):

By default sqoop does not support incremental update with hcatalog integration, when we try it gives following error

**Append mode for imports is not compatible with HCatalog. Please remove the parameter--append-mode
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool.validateHCatalogOptions(BaseSqoopTool.java:1561)**

you can use query option to make it work. as described in [this hortonworks document](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.0/bk_dataintegration/content/incrementally-updating-hive-table-with-sqoop-and-ext-table.html)